# aspell dict make on windows: iso-8859-1.cset can not be opened for reading

Tags: python, windows, dictionary, mingw, aspell

I've compilled the aspell with mingw64 and msys on windows to use with enchant and pyenchant, but i still doesn't have any dicts: "aspell dump dicts" returns nothing.

What i'm trying now is do a ./configure, make and make install with a en dict got from http://gnu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ftp/aspell/dict/en/.

The .configure executes successfuly, but make returns:

```
/mingw/bin/prezip-bin.exe -d < en-common.cwl | /mingw/bin/aspell.exe  --lang=en create master ./en-common.rws
Error: The file "/mingw/lib/aspell-0.60/iso-8859-1.cset" can not be opened for reading.
Makefile:108: recipe for target `en-common.rws' failed
make: *** [en-common.rws] Error 1
```

I've already checked the permissions for this file (iso-8859-1.cset), deactivated the anti virus, executed the msys with administrative permissions but nothing solved the problem.
 The file open correctly in any text editor.

My system configuration for this task is:
 Windows 8.1 x64;
 Mingw-64 + MSYS;
 Aspell 0.60

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with how you compile aspell.

I've successfully compiled and run aspell 0.60.61 and dictionary aspell6-en-7.1-0 under Windows 7 x64 under MSYS environment and gcc 4.7.0 (mingw32-4.7.0-posix-dwarf-rev0 to be exact). I haven't solved every issue with it yet, but here is my discovery:

The configure I use is:

```
$ ./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-win32-relocatable
```

When I first compiled aspell I got compile errors:

```
common/file_util.cpp: In function 'bool acommon::need_dir(acommon::ParmString)':
common/file_util.cpp:49:32: error: 'asc_isalpha' was not declared in this scope
```

so I followed this guide [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/aspell-user/2007-10/msg00008.html) (which I guess you probably also did) to bypass this error.

Everything compiled and aspell can be run, but then it kept giving me path resolving errors, including the error you got, or something like

```
Error: The file "/usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60//usr/loc`enter code here`al/lib/aspell-0.60/en_US.multi" can not be opened for reading.
```

(I didn't keep the original message but it's something like that)
I even tried to use --data-dir, --dict-dir, or --local-data-dir options but the only time I made it work is when I'm in /usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60/ folder and set --data-dir to ./

But it shouldn't be like that, so I looked back to file_util.cpp and discovered that the code I skipped has something to do with path handling. Later on I found this [Japanese article](http://mikanya.dip.jp/memo/2007-09-07-1) pointing out that asc_isalpha is defined in asc_tyoe.hpp. So I add

```
#include "asc_ctype.hpp"
```

to file_util.cpp, and recompile aspell again. Then I tried to compile aspell6-en-7.1-0, this time there is no error and the dictionary compiled successfully.

The problem now is that aspell is still not able to find dictionaries by default, it still gives error message like:

```
Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".
```

even though aspell has correct data-dir by default:

```
$ aspell config data-dir
/usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60
```

But at least --data-dir option works now, so I can use aspell like this:

```
$ aspell --data-dir=/usr/local/lib/aspell-0.60/ -c test.txt
```

Hopefully you can solve your aspell problem as well.

Reference:

> http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/aspell-user/2007-10/msg00008.html
>   [http://mikanya.dip.jp/memo/2007-09-07-1](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/aspell-user/2007-10/msg00008.html)
>   https://www.mail-archive.com/aspell-user%40gnu.org/msg02226.html
>   http://osdir.com/ml/general/2014-12/msg10031.html

many thanks to these articles/webpages that help me figure out how to make aspell work